# Subspaces topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces

Let $A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 |x^2 +y^2 <1\}$ and $B=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | 1 < x^2 +y^2  <2\}$ , both taken  with the subspaces  topology of $\mathbb{R}^2 $.

Choose the correct statement

1. Every  continious  function from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$  has  bounded image
2. There  exists  a  non -constant continious  function  from $B$ to $\mathbb{N}$
3. For  every  surjective  continious  function from $A \cup B $to a  topological  space  $X , X$   has  atmost two connected  components
4. $B$ is homeomorphic to the unit circle

**My attempt** :

Option 1 is false  take  $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{1+x+y}$

Option 2 is false because $\mathbb{N}$ is not connected . continuous  image of connected is connected

Option 3 is true by pasting lemma.

Option 4 is false because  $B$ is not compact.

Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your function is not well-defined on $A$ since the denominator has zeroes in the domain. You can look at $f(x, y) = \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2 - 1}$ instead. (Why does this work?)
2. The question does not ask for the function to be surjective. So just $\Bbb N$ being disconnected does not work. (Note that in the case of $\Bbb N$, the only connected subsets are the singletons. Use that instead.)
3. How are you using pasting lemma? Pasting lemma would be useful to construct a continuous function on $A \cup B$ if you were given continuous functions on $A$ and $B$ individually. But here, the question already gives you a continuous function on the union.
4. This reasoning is correct.

Comment: okay but for option $3$ If we take $X= \mathbb{R}$ then $\mathbb{R}$  has  two connected components   but $A\cup B$ is  a  disconnected set .This lead to contradiction because $\mathbb{R}$ is connected

Comment: can you  elaborate  more about option $ 3 ?$

Comment: @jasmine: It's not clear what you are saying. You can very well have a surjective function from a disconnected set to a connected set. In this case, you can take $f$ to be defined as $x^2 + y^2$ on $A$ and as $x^2 + y^2 - 1$ on $B$. This gives you a surjection $A \cup B \to \Bbb R$. In any case, the question is only saying that $X$ has **at most** two connected components. This is true because the image of a connected component is again connected.

Comment: okay  thanks you @Aryaman Maithani Got it